# SQL find exact date after 1 year

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Below is my table, how can I find out the exact date after 1 year since the createdDateTime. Hopefully there is a best practice way which would also consider the leap year issue.

```
    ID     CreatedDateTime
---------------------------
    a      2015-06-02 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: `DATEADD(year,1,CreatedDateTime)`

Comment: Do you know about the DATEADD functions?

Comment: It depends on what your definition of handling leap years is... DATEADD takes them into consideration but sometimes people don't like the way it handles leap years. For example DATEADD(year, 1, '2012-02-29') will return February, 28 2013. I think this is the correct way to do but others want it to return March, 01 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function.

```
DATEADD (datepart , number , date )

SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, 1, CreatedDateTime) 
FROM dbo.YOURTABLE
```